# How should one lock Wine apps to the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, wine, launcher, icons, unity-dash

I have installed the Rosetta Stone language learning software successful with Wine. When I click and drag the Rosetta Stone icon from the Dash to the launcher, the other icons make way for it, but when I release the mouse button the icon doesn't stay.

How can I lock the application to the launcher?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- run the app
- right-click its icon
- select "keep the launcher in dock" or similarly named option.

EDIT: it didn't work, so second way:

- install Alacarte or menulibre (these are menu editors)
- create a custom launcher with command like `wine "/home/<your_username>/Downloads/Rosetta Stone.exe"`
- drag it from menu to the dock.

It should work, but if we aren't lucky, you may have two icons when the app is running - the launcher you created and wine icon (because wine will be running).

Comment: I did. It kept a Wine icon there. Upon clicking it it did nothing but throb.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe it just pinned Wine without any app to run. You can install alacarte. It's a menu editor. Then you can create a custom launcher with command like `wine "/home/<your_username>/Downloads/Rosetta Stone.exe"`. Then drag it from menu to the dock. (In the worst case you will have two icons when the app is running.)